# I'm doing a pixel command and I ran into a problem, when I enter the command: AttributeError: 'Member' object does not have attribute 'avatar_as

Tags: discord.py, bots, pixel

## Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=10.0, type=commands.BucketType.user)
    async def pixel(self, ctx, user=None):
        """Pixelates an image."""
        if user is None:
            for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
                img = await self.bot.dagpi.image_process(
                    asyncdagpi.ImageFeatures.pixel(), attachment.proxy_url
                )
                file = discord.File(fp=img.image, filename=f"pixel.{img.format}")
                await ctx.send(file=file)

        else:
            userID = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", user)
            try:
                user = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(userID)
            except BaseException:
                await ctx.send("No user found.")
                return

            url = str(user.avatar_as(format="png", size=1024))
            img = await self.bot.dagpi.image_process(
                asyncdagpi.ImageFeatures.pixel(), url
            )
            file = discord.File(fp=img.image, filename=f"pixel.{img.format}")
            await ctx.send(file=file)
```

I tried replacing avatar_url_as with avatar_us, nothing changed.

I ask you to correct my code, and write me an answer, I will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [migration to discord 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=avatar_as), `Member.avatar_url_as` was replaced by [`Member.avatar.replace`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Asset.replace).

Also be aware that you could also need `Member.default_avatar.replace` in case of no avatar.